# Line Bundles on Local Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a local ring and $L$ a module over $A$ which is projective and of rank one. Does it follow that $L$ is isomorphic to $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Every projective module over a local ring is free. See for example [The Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/058Z).

Since your module is of rank 1, it is isomorphic to $A$ as an $A$-module.